# function to know if is Tablet, iPad, Smartphone?

Tags: android, ios, appcelerator

Is there a way to know if the app is running in: Android Tablet, iPad, or Smarthphone (handheld) ?

I am using classic development with Titanium Appcelerator SDK 5.3.0GA.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My [TitanUp](https://github.com/jpriebe/TitanUp) library has a function that can tell you if you're running on a tablet.  It checks explicitly for ipad, and then if it's running on android, it considers anything with a screen of 6.25 inches or greater to be a tablet.

Here's how you use it:

`var TU = require ('/TitanUp/TitanUp');
    TU.Device.getIsTablet();`

If you don't want to use the whole library, you could just look at the code in Device.js that sets the _screensize variable.  Trace through those functions, and you can get the logical density factor which lets you calculate the physical width / height, from which you can get the diagonal screen size in inches.

Comment: Thanks Jason, i will take a look

Answer (score 5):

You can differ between between tablet and handheld with

**In controller:**

```
Alloy.isTablet or Alloy.isHandheld.
```

**TSS:**

```
"Label[platform=ios formFactor=handheld]": {
    backgroundColor: "#f00",
    text: 'iPhone'
},
```

[function to know if is Tablet, iPad, Smartphone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37870374/function-to-know-if-is-tablet-ipad-smartphone)

http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Alloy_Styles_and_Themes

Comment: i am not using Allow, i am using classic development... does it work ?